# REACT - fetch json data from url and display it

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I am new to REACT and I was trying to learn how to get and display a specific parameter from a json style message stored in an url.

For instance, the video I was trying to show, is stored in and url, which is a field of the json message itself, so it would look like this:

```
{

    "type": "video", 

    "url": "http://somewebsite.com/wantedvideo.mp4" 
}
```

From what i've read, `fetch()` is one way to get the data, but unfortunately I couldn't seem to understand what can be missing in the code I tried:

Here's my newbie attempt:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state={
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    fetch('https://demo7443497.mockable.io/stream/video')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((findresponse)=>{
      console.log(findresponse.url)
      this.setState({
        data:findresponse.url,
      })
    })
  }

  render()
  {
    return(
        <div>
          {this.state.data.url} 
        </div> 
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

My `render()` always looked suspiciously too simple for me, so my apologies for any "mad" mistakes I may have made

PS: If instead of a video there was some other data format such as an image or plain text in the url of the `url` field, is there an disavantadge in using the same code to fech it?

Thank you

Comment: First things first, looking at above code,  data variable in state is an array and you are trying to display this.state.data.url, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setState({
  data: findresponse.url,
})
```

You are setting `url` value to `data` and

in `render` accessing the `data.url`. (**`url` on `data` which does not exists**).

If you just put `{this.state.data}`,you will get `url` value.

Also, if you are getting Object from response then declare `state` as

```
this.state = {
  data: {}, //instead []
}
```

EDIT :

e.g. to display video using  video control as per comment.

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src={this.state.data} type="video/mp4" /> 
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Working [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2x4l75275)

Comment: Indeed! However I'm afraid it now displays the url to the video and not the video itself, is there any detail I should touch in order to obtain the video running?

Comment: Just displaying the url is not way to display Video.Please use either video tag  from html5 or other options

Comment: @OhWords Please check EDIT

Comment: I'm very sorry for bothering you again but 2 small things made me curious: 
When changing data from "[]" to "{}" I got an error of "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
With this in mind I tried leaving it as it was, or changing data to {} as you suggested, but also added '.toString()' to  'this.state.data' in the render.

Comment: Both of those "solutions" gave the following result:  for some reason I believe the Html is not recognizing the variable, as the video controls showed up, but everything is greyed out and the video doesn't play, like it didn't exist. Is there a chance we missed something?

Comment: @OhWords my bad.Please keep it to `[]`.See working demo in update answer :)

Comment: Edit: I clicked in the sandbox working demo and the result was the video still greyed out, I asked a friend to test in his computer and the same happened. Could someone confirm this? And if it isn't working, did you detect any possible flaw? Everything seems to be correct...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide a simple App component which look like this -

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Player } from 'video-react';

class App extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://demo7443497.mockable.io/stream/video')
            .then( resp => resp.json())
            .then((data)=> {
                this.setState({
                    data: data.url
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Player
                playsInline
                src={ this.state.data }
            />
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Import css -

`import "node_modules/video-react/dist/video-react.css"; // import css`

`@import "~video-react/styles/scss/video-react"; // or import scss`

Add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/video-react.css" />` inside `index.html`

Try this it will work for all browsers.